# Android ActionBar and content position

Tags: android

I'm using the support package ActionBar.  Just using standard "setContentView".  It seems like the action bar is simply floating above the content, rather than displacing it.  I'm sure there's a really dumb thing I'm doing, but its driving me nuts.  I would expect my content to show below the action bar.

Also, using viewpager with tabs on another screen.  Same issue, but worse.  Content takes up whole screen, and actionbar and tabs are on top.

Comment: Can you post the XML for your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [windowActionBarOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBarOverlay) is set to true.  That would cause the behavior you are describing where the ActionBar merely sits on top of the content.

Comment: Yep.  Was including another project that set it globally.  Had to be something simple.  Thanks!